# JMeter - Pause the request if it gives an error

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I'm using Apache JMeter to send thousands of HTTP requests with 3 seconds of delay in between. The response body is json and starts with {"errors":[ ], ...}. If there is an error it will be in the [ ]. If there is no error than [ ] will be empty.

I want JMeter to pause for a short period of time if it receives an error, and try the request again. So that it'll add in additional buffer when needed.

Do I need a script for this? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of errors by adding a [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) as a child of the Sampler which returns the JSON and configuring it like:

[image]

It will extract the number of entries in `errors` [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) and store it into `errors` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Then you can use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to check if the number of errors is above zero, it can be done using [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) like:

```
${__jexl3(${errors} > 0,)}
```

[image]

and finally you can introduce a delay using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Add a [JSR223 Post Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to the  Test Plan level, Thread Group or to a sampler based on your requirement.

Add following code into the script area to check the error and introduce a delay after error if any.

```
int delayOnErrorInMillis = 5000

if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().startsWith('{"errors":')){
    log.info("ERROR !")
    sleep(delayOnErrorInMillis)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I'm using CSV Data Set Config, HTTP Request, Save Responses to a file and View Results Tree. Where should I add JSR223 Post Processor with all of them? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to add the JSR223 Post Processor to the HTTP Request